# Getting "undefined" result when using the logical operator "&&" in a JavaScript If..Else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

The code is for selecting the federal poverty level (**var fpl**) percentage category base on the income (**var income**).  When I run this script, my result is "undefined" when I use the **&&** logic operator.  If I use the **||** logic operator, I get the wrong and same answer - "101-185%" - no matter what number I use for **var income**.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function FPL() {   

    var income = '4200.00';
    var fs = '1';

        var fpl;  
        if(fs == '1') {
            if(income < '1022.00')
               fpl = "0-100%";  
            if (income > '1022.00' && income < '1882.00') 
               fpl = "101-185%";   
            if (result3 > '1882.00' && income < '2033.00') 
               fpl = "186%-200%";
            if (income < '2033.00')
               fpl ="'201% & Over";

            return fpl;                

        }             

        result6 = 'Federal Poverty Level: ' + fpl;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result6;
 }   

</script>
```

Are the logic operators in an Else..If statement used differently in JavasScript?

Comment: you have no `else` ... and .. your code will never execute the last two statements ... and fpl will be undefined if none of those conditions are true ... i.e .. if income >= '2033.00'

Comment: Also, be careful while using strings as numbers... try `'4200.00' > '10000000000'` in your console and see what you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, lets check your code because you have some mistakes, I'll add comments on where they are.

**note:** also be careful when comparing strings, for example `"400" > "100000"` will return `true`. so if you want to compare values, parse them before comparing.

```
  function FPL() {   

    var income = '4200.00';
    var fs = '1';

        //set a default value here to fpl or inside an else.
        var fpl;  
        if(fs == '1') {
            //on all these ifs, you dont have an else, then if your income doesnt fill your criteria, it will be undefined.
            if(income < '1022.00')
               fpl = "0-100%";  
            if (income > '1022.00' && income < '1882.00') 
               fpl = "101-185%";   
            if (result3 > '1882.00' && income < '2033.00') //result3 doesnt even exist, this will throw an error.
               fpl = "186%-200%";
            if (income < '2033.00')
               fpl ="'201% & Over";

            // if you return here, how do you expect the following code to execute? 
            // you just needed to continue the workflow
            return fpl;                

        }             
        //this code is never executed, unless fs is different than 1 (but it is hardcoded)
        result6 = 'Federal Poverty Level: ' + fpl;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result6;
 }
```

here you have your code without the mistakes and fixed.

```js
function FPL() {
  //parse the value to get the number.
  var income = parseFloat('4200.00');
  var fs = '1';

  var fpl;
  if (fs == '1') {
    if (income < parseFloat('1022.00'))
      fpl = "0-100%";
    else if (income > parseFloat('1022.00') && income < parseFloat('1882.00'))
      fpl = "101-185%";
    else if (income > parseFloat('1882.00') && income < parseFloat('2033.00'))
      fpl = "186%-200%";
    else if (income < parseFloat('2033.00'))
      fpl = "'201% & Over";
    else
      fpl = 'default value';
  }

  result6 = 'Federal Poverty Level: ' + fpl;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result6;
}

FPL();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and comments, the script worked. Learned something new.  Thank you, and again, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

after a quick look, you have a mistake on this line:

> if (result3 > '1882.00' && income < '2033.00')

"result3" is indeed undefined, try with "income"

Comment: No sorry, that's a typo error, don't know how that got in there, but it should be also "income".

Answer (score 0):

You `income` value doesn't belong to any of your `if` statements (I suppose, you thought to write `if (income > /* instead of < */ "2033.00")`, so the `fpl` still undefined